# Python:How to predict NAN values using linear regression?

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, prediction

I have some Nan values in my dataset and I want to replace them by predicted values.

Here is my dataset :

```
    code    v0      v1   v2      v3

0   zd56    NaN     25  189.3   0.07
1   wd_89   12.9    22  193.6   0.12
2   wd_891  13.0    50  193.8   0.43
3   nsw_20  14.5    26  180.2   0.16
4   lstm5   9.1     13  170.9   0.13
5   mus_80  10.0    20  186.8   0.11
6   gs      10.0    22  187.0   0.05
7   df00    NaN     12  189.9   0.10
```

I want to replace those two Nans in colulmn v0 by prediction of linear regression depending upon the columns v1,v2 and v3.
If there was no missing values, I would do this:

```
X = df[['v1', 'v2', 'v3']]
y = df['v0'].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.8, random_state=0)

regressor = LinearRegression()  
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': y_pred})
df1
```

But I'm aware that we can't pass missing values to the algorithm, and even after some researches, I couldn't find a solution to my question.

train_test_split method splits randomly the dataset.
I wonder if there is a way to split "manually" : put all the missing values to y_test.

I do appreciate all the answers that can be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Imputer might be the one you are looking for.

A relevant snippet from sklearn imputer documentation is shown below. 
Link: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
>>> imp_mean = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
>>> imp_mean.fit([[7, 2, 3], [4, np.nan, 6], [10, 5, 9]])
SimpleImputer()
>>> X = [[np.nan, 2, 3], [4, np.nan, 6], [10, np.nan, 9]]
>>> print(imp_mean.transform(X))
[[ 7.   2.   3. ]
 [ 4.   3.5  6. ]
 [10.   3.5  9. ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to split your DataFrame first into one on which you train the model and another for which you're trying to predict missing values. You can do this by:

```
df_to_train_on = df[~pd.isnull(df[column_name_with_missing_values])]
df_with_missing_values = df[pd.isnull(df[column_name_with_missing_values])]
```

Then split each individually into X and y. Whether you want to do additional splitting with train_test_split on `df_to_train_on` depends if you want to evaluate your model before applying it on `df_with_missing_values`. If you don't, just treat X from `df_with_missing_values` as `X_test`.

Answer (score 0):

Directly put all the missing values to separated dataframe, then use `train_test_split(...)`, you could use boolean indexing.

```
nan_rows = df[df['v0'].isna()]

df.dropna(inplace=True)

X = df[['v1', 'v2', 'v3']]
y = df['v0']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.8, random_state=0)

x_test = pd.concat([x_test, nan_rows.drop(['v0'], axis=1)])
y_test = pd.concat([y_test, nan_rows['v0']])
```